# Disable option to move FeinCMS contenttypes within a region

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, contenttype, feincms

I'd like to disable the option to move FeinCMS contenttypes whithin a region.
Does anyone have any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible currently.

What's the reasoning behind this feature request?

Comment: Ok. Well, we are building a website for multiple countries. There will be one master version where normal editing can be done. The countries may only edit certain values. We don't want them to be able to move stuff around.

Comment: You could add another AdminSite instance, and add ModelAdmin subclasses containing only the necessary fields for them. Use your own forms (ModelAdmin.form) and your own querysets (ModelAdmin.get_query_set). Register the ModelAdmin subclass as follows: admin.site.register(Page.content_type_for(YourContentType), YourContentTypeModelAdmin) -- this should work.